# Pointer Arithmetic equivalence

Tags: c, pointers

I have got this function written in C.

Are them two statements equivalent?

```
void dot_prod(float *A, int m, float *B, float *C) {
    int i, j, z, k;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < m; k++) {
                C[i * m + k] += A[i * m + j] * B[m * j + k];
                //*(C + i * m + k) += *(A + i * m + j) * (*(B + m * j + k)); // is equivalent?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is

`C[i * m + k] += A[i * m + j] * B[m * j + k]`

equivalent to

`*(C + i * m + k) += *(A + i * m + j) * (*(B + m * j + k))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost.

```
C[i * m + k] += A[i * m + j] * B[m * j + k]
```

is equivalent to

```
*(C + (i * m + k)) += *(A + (i * m + j)) * (*(B + (m * j + k)))
```

This is different than without the extra parentheses, since the addition in the indices may overflow, in which case the pointer/integer addition is not necessarily associative, depending on the sizes of `int` and pointers.

Comment: Can we say the latter expression is safer?

Comment: @tail No, they are exactly identical. Neither is safer. But the first one makes it much clearer what is happening, which also is a good thing to avoid mistakes.

Comment: All versions become safer if you replace `int` with `size_t` in the original code -- `size_t` is guaranteed to be large enough for any index (which `int` might not be) and is unsigned so has clean overflow semantics as well.